# Toss an unbalanced coin twice; Y is the number of heads. Depending on value of y actually oberved what is the MLE of p?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

The original question says, "It is known the probability $p$ of tossing heads on an unbalanced coin is either $1/4$ or $3/4$. The coin is tossed twice and $Y$ is the number of heads. For each value of $Y$, which two values for $p$ (answer: $1/4$ or $3/4$) maximize the probability that $Y = y$? Find the MLE of $p$ depending on $y$."

So, I said that $p = 3/4$ maximizes $Y$ because if there is a higher probability of tossing a heads then that will maximize the number of heads. Is there something more complicated to that that I am missing?

Then to find the MLE, we are looking at $L(p) = $product of $p^y(1-p)^{n-y}$, and that is what we will use as out likelihood function? Or does it need to be the maximum of that?

Comment: What do you mean by mle?

Comment: You seem really in need of **definitions** here. How do they define the MLE, already?

Comment: @danimal Maximum Likelihood Estimator. (Did you look at the tags?)

Comment: @Did thanks. I did look at the tags and I know what they mean but that doesn't mean that MLE is universally used...

Comment: @danimal And yet it is.

Answer (score 0):

If $Y$ is the number of heads in two throws, then it can take the values 0, 1 and 2. For *each* of these three values (the "$y$" s) you're asked which $p\in\{{1\over4},{3\over4}\}$ will maximise it. Let the probability of a head be $p$.

For $Y=0$ you need two tails, the probability of which is $$p(Y=0)=(1-p)^2$$, which is 9/16 if $p=1/4$ and is 1/16 if $p=3/4$, so for $Y=0$, its probability is maximised for $p=1/4$.

For $Y=1$ you need one tail and one head, in either order, so that $$p(Y=1) = 2p(1-p)$$ which is 3/8 for *both* values of $p$.

For $Y=2$ you need two heads, for which 
$$p(Y=2) = p^2$$ which is 9/16 for $p=3/4$ and 1/16 for $p=1/4$, so here $p=3/4$ maximises this.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. So then I will find the likelihood function, L(p), for Y = 0, Y = 1, and Y=2. When I did that I got that for Y = 0 L(p) = (1-p)^2n. Then taking the natural log and the derivative I got that the MLE = 0. Is that possible?